# Finding similar items using Microsoft Cognitive Services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Which Microsoft Cognitive Services (or Azure Machine Learning services?) is best and least work to use to solve the problem of finding similar articles given an article. An article is a string of text. And assuming I do not have user interaction data about the articles.

Are there anything in Microsoft Cognitive Services that can solve this problem out-of-the-box? It seems I cannot use the Recommendations API since I don't have interaction/user data.

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that Text Analytics API may be a good use for this scenario, at least not yet.

There are really two types of similarities:

**1.    Surface similarity (lexical) – Similarity by presence of words/alphabets**

If we are looking for surface similarity, try fuzzy matching/lookup (SQL Server Integration Services – provides a component for this.), or approximate similarity functions ([Jaro-Winkler distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance), [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)) etc.  This would be easier as it would not require you to create a custom machine learning model.

**2.    Semantic similarity – Similarity by meaning of words**

If we are looking for Semantic similarity, then you need to go for semantic clustering, word embedding, DSSM (Deep semantic similarity model) etc.
this is harder to do, as it would require you to train your own machine learning model based on an annotated corpus.

Luis Cabrera | Text Analytics Program Manager | Cloud AI Platform, Microsoft

Comment: So there's no API for text comparison that would give a similarity score? :-(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Text Analytics API.

examples are available here. https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/text-analytics-api

Comment: hi Narasimha,

Thanks for your reply. In your link, I can only find Sentiment Analysis, Key phrase extraction, Topic detection and Language detection APIs. I cannot find anything that can find similar items (articles) out-of-the-box. (The reason I asked is, it is possible to create a machine learning pipeline for example using Spark to solve the problem, but I am trying to find an out-of-the-box solution or require minimal custom coding)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the Text Analytics API [1] as @Narasimha suggested. You would put your strings through the **Topic detection API**, and then come up with a metric (say, Similarity = count(Matching topics) - count(Non Matching topics)) that could order each string against the others for similarity. This would just require one API call and a little JSON parsing.

[1] https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/text-analytics-api

Answer (score 0):

**Sentence similarity** or **semantic textual similarity** is a measure of how similar two pieces of text are, or to what degree they express the same meaning.

This Microsoft's GitHub repo for NLP provide some sample wich could be used from Azure VM and Azure ML : https://github.com/microsoft/nlp/tree/master/examples/sentence_similarity

> This folder contains examples and best practices, written in Jupyter notebooks, for building sentence similarity models. The gensen and pretrained embeddings utility scripts are used to speed up the model building process in the notebooks.
>   The sentence similarity scores can be used in a wide variety of applications, such as search/retrieval, nearest-neighbor or kernel-based classification methods, recommendations, and ranking tasks.